# Cordova API Offline

Tags: javascript, apache-cordova, rest

Estou com uma duvida, ja fiz algumas pesquisas, mas não achei nada concreto e não sei se oque eu quero fazer é possível. Então gostaria de saber se podem me ajudar?

Eu estou montando um app que consumirá uma API Rest para listagem de produto. Eu preciso fazer com que no primeiro acesso ele bote esses itens em cache para consumir quando estiver offline. Tem como fazer? Podem me ajudar com algum exemplo ou links onde consigo pegar algum exemplo pra entender melhor como fazer?

Comment: Pesquise por *Service Worker*

Answer (score 0):

O que você está procurando é plugin *apache-cordova* para *localStorage*.

Com *localStorage* você passa a ter um banco de dados local em seu app, desta forma você pode carregar esses dados de que mencionou, neste banco de dados local, e acessa-los e edita-los no momento que mai lhe for oportuno.

Este [Link](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.7.0/cordova/storage/localstorage/localstorage.html), é a documentação de como usar o *localStorage* nativo do *apache-crodova*.

Este outro [link](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html), mostra outras opções com Storage, também nativos do *apache-cordova*.

Todas essas opções acima, trabalham com o storage nativo do dispositivo.

Eu uso uma solução mais avançada com SqLite, que é um banco de dados próprio para *aplicativos mobiles*. Gosto dele pois as outras opções podem limitar o tamanho do meu storage, já o SqLite essa gestão do recurso é melhor.

[Este plugin](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage#readme) é muito bom, inclusive é indicado no site do apache-cordova.